# Wordpress multisite subdomain resolution

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4

I have a Wordpress multisite (I am using Apache 2.4 on an Ubuntu 20.04 server on AWS). The structure is a main site -- say mainsite.com -- and three subdomains:

aaa.mainsite.com
bbb.mainsite.com
ccc.mainsite.com

Everything works, except for one problem: aaa, bbb, and ccc.mainsite.com do not resolve to their respective home pages, resolving to the mainsite.com home page instead. All of the links underneath the subdomains, however, resolve correctly: so aaa.mainsite.com/somelink, for example, goes to the right place.

IMPORTANT NOTE: This site has been moved from another server, where it was working. And when I add a new subdomain, it works correctly, but the old ones still do not.

I have a DNS A record pointing to mainsite.com, as well as one for each subdomain, and they are all working, resolving to my server's IP. My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

And here is the VirtualHost file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName mainsite.com
        ServerAlias *.mainsite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mainsite
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AddHandler type-map .var
        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.

        # RewriteLog now deprecated
        LogLevel debug info warn

        <Directory var/www/mainsite>
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mainsite.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mainsite.com/privkey.pem

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName mainsite.com
        ServerAlias *.mainsite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mainsite
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AddHandler type-map .var
        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.

        # RewriteLog now deprecated
        LogLevel debug info warn

        <Directory var/www/mainsite>
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I can tell you that your problem is most definitely with either Wordpress or Apache, your DNS settings seems correct to me (though it's best to just create one A record for the web server and then CNAME everything to that record, makes it easier if you want to move webservers).

Comment: Thanks. I would have preferred to do it that way, but AWS Route 53, which handles my DNS, has restrictions on CNAME records that make it difficult.